# upload a file to Owncloud through a .BAT file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, file-upload, command-line, owncloud

can i upload a file to Owncloud server using command line? in my case i want to write a BAT script in that makes a full backup of my Mysql database and upload it to Owncloud in order to use it later

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this.  First method that came to mind was a CRON job to export the mySQL database to a directory.  Then use the Owncloud client running on the computer/server to sync it to your Owncloud account.

http://owncloud.org/sync-clients/